# Animate on scroll - AOS library : Is there a way to change the distance for fade in effect of element?

Tags: javascript, css, onscroll

I ven been searching online for a while but cant find any answers. Im using the AOS library for animations on scroll. I am using the effect 'fade-left' but want the fade in effect to start 'further away' so the fading becomes longer. Is that possible? Thanks!

```
AOS.init({
    duration: 1200
})

<div class="elm" data-aos="fade-left"></div>
```

Comment: Just create a [mcve] in the question so we can inspect, log and trace the code. Make sure you link all required resources from CDN sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the src>js>scss>_animations.scss file you can change the $aos-distance variable at the top that defaults to 100px